# How to generate SQL statement from List?

Tags: c#, sql, list, visual-studio-2005

If I have a list of Strings, ie. `List<String>`, how can I generate a SQL statement such as:

```
SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN ('String1','String2','String3')
```

where `'String1','String2','String3'` are the contents of `List<String>`?

No LINQ etc. as I am using VS2005.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried)? We like to see the effort you have put into this and understand where you are stuck before we answer.

Comment: i think you should use single qout in query not double.

Comment: No one's worried about SQL injection nowadays?? EVERY answer here is vulnerable.

Comment: Be careful, all answers so far contain SQL injection and should not be used. Use parameters instead of SQL literals.

Comment: @walther: what is your suggestion?

Comment: @usr: how do have a dynamic number of parameters? Do you have to use something like `List<DbParameter>`?

Comment: @Cj7 I have answered with a parameter-based solution.

Comment: Like usr said, use parameterized queries. Forget about those answers showing how to concatenate strings together. I'll post my solution a bit later, have some work to do at the moment.

Comment: @CJ7: Look at my answer. Its perfect and working.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look on following version

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var list = new List<string> {"String1", "String2", "String3"};
        string values = ArrayToString(list);
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN ( {0} )", values);
    }

    private static string ArrayToString(IEnumerable<string> array)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string element in array)
        {
            if (result.Length > 0)
            {
                result.Append(", ");
            }
            result.Append("'");
            result.Append(element);
            result.Append("'");
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

result statement `SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN ( 'String1', 'String2', 'String3' )`

Comment: Are you missing something from the line containing `{0}`?

Comment: Nope, it's String.Format Method,For example string.Format("At {0} in {1}, the temperature was {2} degrees.", dat, city, temp); where {0}, {1}, {2} are prams. take a look here please http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Comment: How does it know to use `values` for the params?

Comment: @CJ7: Static method String.Format accepts, as a second parameter, an object array that contains zero or more objects to format (so, also a string)   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> lst=new List<string>();lst.Add("Hello");lst.Add("Hello World");
string s="";
foreach(string l in lst)s+="\""+l+"\"";
s=Regex.Replace(s,"\"\"","\",\"");

string output="SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 ("+s+")";
```

Comment: foreach(string l in lst)s+="\""+l+"\""; not good solution, take a look on *StringBuilder*

Comment: @GSerjo `StringBuilder` would be good option if there are large no of string to be concatenated..In this situation there would hardly be 5-10 strings..using `StringBuilder` doesnt make **sense** HERE!

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
        List<String> strlist = new List<string>();
        strlist.Add("st1");
        strlist.Add("st2");
        strlist.Add("st3");

        string query = "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN (";

        for (int i = 0; i < strlist.Count; i++)
        {
            query += "\'" + strlist[i] + "\'" + (i == strlist.Count - 1 ? "" : ",");
        }

        query += ")";
```

Comment: You are missing the string terminators.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said its an internal operation and hence there is no need to be worried about SQL Injection, then you can achieve what you want by this.

```
string str = "";

foreach(string s in list)
  str += "'" + s.Replace("'", "''") + "',";

str = str.SubString(0, str.Length - 1);

str = "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN (" + str + ")";

//str will have your command ready.
```

I have tested it. It works perfectly.

Comment: str += s + "\", "; not good solution, take a look on *StringBuilder*

Comment: @GSerjo StringBuilder would be good option if there are large no of string to be concatenated..In this situation there would hardly be 5-10 strings..using StringBuilder doesnt make sense HERE!

Comment: I see, but should add some suggestion, it's just example. No one will write ' please note i've big list of params', so your version is BAD

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Add("string1");
items.Add("string2");
items.Add("string3");
string AllItems = "";
foreach (string item in items)
{
    AllItems += string.Format("\"{0}\",",item);
}
AllItems = AllItems.TrimEnd(',');
string YourSQLQuery = string.Format("SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN ({0})", AllItems);
MessageBox.Show(YourSQLQuery);
```

Comment: AllItems += string.Format("\"{0}\",",item); not good solution, take a look on *StringBuilder*

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the other answers that have been submitted so far. They contain SQL injection for no obvious reason.

```
    List<String> strlist = new List<string>();
    strlist.Add("st1");
    strlist.Add("st2");
    strlist.Add("st3");

    var dynamicPart = string.Join(", ",
     Enumerable.Range(0, strlist.Count).Select(i => "@" + i).ToArray());
    for(i = 0 to strlist.Count)
     { /* add parameter to SqlCommand here with name ("@" + i) */ }
    string query = "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN (" +
     dynamicPart + ")";
```

Use parameters instead of literals for multiple reasons (research them!).

And instead of a clumsy concatenation loop use `string.Join` which does all of that for us.

Comment: Ok, he can use a loop to add to a list, then. Or use one of the LINQ libraries for VS05.

Comment: Moreover even if you have to use LINQ why have `string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, strlist.Count).Select(i => "@" + i).ToArray();` when you can do `string.Join(", ", strlist.Select(i => "@" + i));`. And also no need to Convert using `ToArray()`. `string.Join` takes an `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: That enumerable overload is new to .NET 4.5 (or 4.0, not sure). The OP can't use it.

Comment: It is an internal operation. No chance of any user input. Should I still safe-guard against injection?

Comment: It is a matter of correctness. What if one of your strings contains a quote? Your app will break. It is best to once build the correct code and reuse it for years in other places. It pays off big time.

Comment: What if one of the strings does contain a quote with your solution?  What is the result?

Comment: The dynamic SQL will look like "select ... IN (@p0, @p1, ...)". There are no literals. They are passed in as SQL parameters which are always safe.

Answer (score 0):

Don't for get to guard against SQL Injection.

```
string sql_list = "";
foreach (string s in lst)
    sql_list+=string.Format("{0},",s.Replace("'","''"));
sql_list = string.Format("({0})",sql_list.substring(0,sql_list.length-2));
```

that might help some, and use string builder, or not.

Answer (score 0):

To properly handle sql injection, a better answer may be to make the query of the form...

```
select results.* from (
    select pk from table where column=value1 union
    select pk from table where column=value2 union
    select pk from table where column=value3 union
    select pk from table where column=value4 union
    select pk from table where column=value5
) filtered join table as results on filtered.pk = results.pk
```

and then make it more c# friendly

```
string items_filter = "";
int item_index=0;
OracleParameterCollection parameters = new OracleParameterCollection(); // Not sure what class to use here exactly, but just collect a bunch of stored procedure parameters

foreach (string item in list_of_items) {
    string item_name = string.Format("i_item{0}",item_index);  
    string item_sql = string.Format("select pk from table where column=:{0} union",item_name);
    parameters.Add(new Parameter("item_name",item));
    item_index+=1;  
}
if (items_filter.IsNullOrEmpty()) 
    return;

string sql = String.Format("select results.* from ({0}) filtered join table as results on filtered.pk = results.pk",items_filter);

OracleCommand c = new OracleCommand();
c.command = sql;
c.parameters = parameters;
c.execute();
```

More or less.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assume your list (List<string>) is named "myList"

// Please put the next line in an external string resource...
string selectStatement = "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN ({0})";

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("(");
foreach(string colName in myList)
    stringBuilder.Append(String.Format("'{0}',", colName));
stringBuilder.Append(")");

return String.Format(selectStatement, stringBuilder.ToString().Replace(",)", ")");
```